# How to know that I'm at the end of tree when iterating?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, trie

I'm writing (inorder) iterator for tree structure (left child pointer, right child pointer, parent pointer) and I'm stuck, because I can't think of a way to stop iterating when I've already visited all nodes. How can I check if the node I'm currently at is the last node of tree?

EDIT

The tree structure here is supposed to be binary trie, I need inorder traversal to achieve lexicological order of node "keys" and I have the recursive version already done - I'm trying to do the iterative version, because a lot of other functions traversing the tree and I'm not really sure how to write the recursive version generic enough to support all the uses.

I'm sorry if my initial question was non-accurate, downvote as you see fit.

Comment: Why are you writing code when you haven't figured out how to determine "the last node" with pencil and paper?

Comment: Have you figured out how to *start* iterating? You stop when there is no "next" node. So figure out how to find the "next" node.

Comment: A simple way is just check whether the current node is the rightmost child of the tree which will be the last node in in-order traversal. To find rightmost child, simply travel all the way right from root until there is no right child. But of course, if you actually implement your FindNextNode function properly, you should arrive at the same conclusion by detecting that you are returning to root from right child or after root and there is no right child.

Comment: are you writing recursive code or not ? [read](http://www.techiedelight.com/inorder-tree-traversal-iterative-recursive/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it recursively, this is inherent in the algorithm, you don't need to manually check, as per the following pseudo-code:

```
def processTree(node):
    if node == null: return
    processTree(node.left)
    print(node.value)
    processTree(node.right)

processTree(rootNode)
```

Consider the point where you process the very last node, say `7` in the following tree:

```
    __1__
   /     \
  2       3
 / \     / \
4   5   6   7
```

At that point, you will have already processed everything to the left and all parents so you will simply step up the tree and exit.

Comment: Question is tagged c++, not python.

Comment: @Barmar, that's pseudo-code! It just happens that Python is an ideal pseudo-code language, if you steer clear of lambdas and that sort of stuff. I'll clarify.

Comment: The C++ code is almost identical, just a few more braces, why not post it that way to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Barmar: because (1) I'm here primarily to teach rather than just provide drop-in code. (2) Very few non-homework questions would use hand-built tree code so homework (or some education) almost certainly what this is. (3) There should be no confusion now as I've explicitly stated it's pseudo-code.

Comment: Anyone who needs to ask a question like this is probably not competent to translate pseudo-code to real code. So you've just replaced one problem with another one for him.

Comment: @Barmar: anyone who hopes to become a programmer better learn *very* fast how to translate ideas into code. Additionally, since I have no idea what their *current* code looks like, it's likely to require integration anyway. No, I think I'll leave it as is for now. If you think a language-specific answer would be better, you should provide it and let the swarm decide. In any case, the C++-specific answer would be to stop wasting time re-inventing the wheel and use the standard library :-)

Comment: @Davar -- The example tree is just a picture.  The way in C++ (and basically most languages) use to denote a node with no children is to have both left and right nodes equal to null.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to calculate the total of nodes before searching the tree, say N. Then you can use a `size_t counter` to count it, i.e. pass the reference of the `counter` into the recursive call to for tree search, and do a `++counter` at each final node.

Comment: How are you going to calculate the number of nodes in the tree without solving the original problem?

Comment: the total number of nodes should be 2^(k-1) where k is the number of layers of the tree. Right?

Comment: How do you find the number of layers of the tree without traversing the tree?

Comment: That also assumes that the tree is balanced.

Comment: It's actually `(2^k)-1`. Look at the example tree in paxdiablo's answer, it has 3 levels and 7 nodes.

Comment: I was thinking about the final node, such as 4,5,6,7. You made good point on the balanced tree. If it is balanced, keep searching the left nodes can find the layers.

Comment: How do you know when to stop searching the left nodes? You're back to the original question.

Comment: When there is no more left children, we stop searching. In the graph above, we start from 1, then 2, then 4, we know that we have 3 layers of the tree. I thought her original question is how to stop searching all the final nodes. Then, we know that we have 4 final nodes by counting the layers. Right? Or I miss something? :)

Comment: I think the main issue there is that even a balanced tree doesn't have to be fully populated. Think of the tree in my answer but without the `7`. Counting the max depth will give you a small *range* of possible node counts rather than an exact value.